# Shell script syntax error no delete mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

output : Error Syntax i don't know position syntax error maybe you can help me!

```
[root@localhost ~]# . test.bash
    bash: test.bash: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
    bash: test.bash: line 23: ` 3 ) mysql -u root -p1234 -e 'USE eventime;DELETE FROM eventime.dt WHERE date1 <(SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),\'%Y-%m-%d\'),\'-1\'),\'%Y-%m-%d\')- INTERVAL 90 DAY);' ;;'
```

Shell Script : I new shell script just syntax error but i can't edit code

```
#!/bin/bash

selection=
until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do
    echo "=============================="
    echo "=========PROGRAM MENU========="
    echo "1 - Show Date and Time"
    echo "2 - Show Data Database"
    echo "3 - Connect Database"
    echo ""
    echo "0 - Back to command"
    echo "=============================="
    echo -n "Enter selection : "
    read selection
    echo ""

    case $selection in
        1 ) dti=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
            echo "This is Date and Time : " $dti ;;

        2 ) mysql -u root -p123456789 -e 'USE eventime;SELECT date1,time1 FROM dt;' ;;

        3 ) mysql -u root -p123456789 -e 'USE eventime;DELETE FROM eventime.dt WHERE date1 <(SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),\'%Y-%m-%d\'),\'-1\'),\'%Y-%m-%d\')- INTERVAL 90 DAY);' ;;

        0 ) Ctrl+Z ;;
        * ) echo "Please enter 1, 2, 3 , 4 or 0"
    esac
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but i can't edit code`, You have a similar question here [Error delete data mysql from shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695432/error-delete-data-mysql-from-shell-script), why can't you resolve it there and not duplicate?

Comment: syntax error TT

Comment: just ("") haha.

Answer (score 1):

change ' to " in the following part as below;

```
3 ) mysql -u root -p123456789 -e "USE eventime;DELETE FROM eventime.dt WHERE date1 <(SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'),'-1'),'%Y-%m-%d')- INTERVAL 90 DAY);" ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `"` in date *format* and other arguments:

```
3 ) mysql -u root -p123456789 -e 'USE eventime;DELETE FROM eventime.dt WHERE date1 <(SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%Y-%m-%d"),"-1"),"%Y-%m-%d")- INTERVAL 90 DAY);' ;;
```